# Typeahead.js - Search in multiple property values

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead, typeahead.js, bloodhound

Please see example below.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R7UvH/2/

How do I make [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) (0.10.1) search for matches in more than one property value? Ideally, within whole `data` (`data.title`, `data.desc` and in all `data.category[i].name`)

```
 datumTokenizer: function(data) {
     // **search in other property values; e.g. data.title & data.desc etc..**
     return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(data.title);
 },
```

Whole example:

```
var data = [{
    title: "some title here",
    desc: "some option here",
    category: [{
        name: "category 1",
    }, {
        name: "categoy 2",
    }]
},
{
    title: "some title here",
    desc: "some option here",
    category: [{
        name: "category 1",
    }, {
        name: "categoy 2",
    }]
}];

var posts = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(data) {
        // **search in other property values; e.g. data.title & data.desc etc..**
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(data.title);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: data
});
posts.initialize();

$('#search-input').typeahead({
    highlight: true
}, {
    name: 'Pages',
    displayKey: 'title',
    source: posts.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        header: '<h3>Pages</h3>'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 31):

[Typeahead 0.10.3 added "support to object tokenizers for multiple property tokenization."](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0103-july-10-2014)

So, your example becomes

```
var posts = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('title', 'desc'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: data
});
```

However, I don't think this will work for properties nested inside, that is, the `data.category` object in your case.

As a side note, if you are using prefetched data, be sure to clear the local storage first, otherwise the new tokenizer won't take effect (Because `datumTokenizer` is used when adding to the search index, and if data is already present in `localStorage`, then the search index will not be updated). I was stuck on this for a while!

Comment: kept working on @timothy solution for days but it did not work for me. This solution works and is more elegant.

Comment: Great solution, thanks. Side note, you can prevent prefetch caching with `prefetch: { cache: false, ... }`

Comment: This works, but alert: **You must specify the properties in the order they appear** in the data's schema; otherwise, it won't work. I think this is a bug in the typeahead since it's astonishing to the user.

Answer (score 14):

`return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(data.title)` returns an array of strings.

So, instead of returning that value: save it (and your other desired values), then concatenate them and return that value...

```
x = Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(data.title);
y = Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(data.desc);
z = Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(data.category[i].name);
return x.concat(y).concat(z);
```

Answer (score 7):

I've implemented a solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/4nnnG/

As you have a local datasource  you need to create individual datasets to enable you to match on multiple data properties. e.g.

```
$('#search-input').typeahead({
    highlight: true
}, {
    name: 'titles',
    displayKey: 'title',
    source: titles.ttAdapter()
}, {
    name: 'descs',
    displayKey: 'desc',
    source: descs.ttAdapter()
}, {
    name: 'cats',
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: cats.ttAdapter()
});
```

Comment: @NullSoulException :D

Comment: @Fresh thanks for taking the time, it is slightly more complicated than I initially presented. I am using multiple sources (which are categorized with headers -exactly the same as per typeahead.js multi source demo http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/). Can you point me to an example of the filter usage? Please note that I want to keep the categorization with headers (media, pages, posts). thanks

Comment: I've been looking into the way filter() and what I thought would help you wouldn't work i.e. build up a list of tokens within the filter. I think you should implement a solution using the way I suggested in my answer, except you'll need to add the categorization headers as you suggested. Hope you find a solution and I'll be interested to see it!